# Inconsistent behaviour in WebView loadUrl() using local html file and #tags - API 7 and API 10

Tags: android, webview

Summary:

Problem whilst trying use a webview to open a standard html file located in the “assets” directory.  The html document contains location anchors throughout, and I try to navigate directly to these when opening the document by supplying a #tag in the URL supplied to the .loadUrl() method of a “WebView” object.  This works correctly and consistently in an emulator with API level 7 ( Android 2.1 Updated), but shows inconsistent behaviour with an emulator with API level 10 ( Android 2.3.3 Updated). These inconsistencies have also been observed on a real device Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.3.

Observations:

With API level 7, each time the .loadUrl() method is called, the page opens and the document is positioned at the correct anchor location as supplied in the  URL#Tag string.

With API level 10, the first time the application is loaded into the emulator or the real device, the behaviour of the .loadUrl() method is as expected. The document opens at the correct anchor position. But in every subsequent call where a URL#tag  string is supplied in the URL, the document opens and appears to scroll to the very bottom of the text on the page, ignoring the #tag. The exception to this is when a document is opened with only a standard URL without the #tag suffix attached.

Relevant code portions:

a) OnCreate:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help_viewer);  
        engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.id_web_engine);  
    // note the “engine” is defined globally to the activity
    }
```

b) OnResume:

```
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        //
        //
    engine.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Simple_help_en.html#about_this_app”);
    // works in API 7, inconsistencies with API 10 
        //
        //  
    }
```

c) OnStop

```
    OnStop () { //added in desperation - but made no difference

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    engine.clearCache(true); 
    engine.clearHistory(); 
    engine = null;
}
```

I'm very new to Android and feel that I've missed something as the balance of  probability would suggest that its more likely to be an error in coding rather than an error in the API. I've searched through the questions/answers online but was unable to find a relevant answer. Can someone please point out my mistake and a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure on the inconsistency, but if you're nulling out engine in onStop (when the activity is no longer visible), you'll get a NullPointerException when coming back to the activity because onCreate won't be called unless the activity is destroyed. Matching calls are - onCreate/onDestroy, onStart/onStop, onResume/onPause.

Comment: Thanks FunkTheMonk, appreciate the reminder on matching life-cycle events/calls.  The code in OnStop was just me shooting in the dark. The problem existed before that code was implemented. I've since removed the code... no change observed. Problem persists.

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Did you find the solution?